# Use result of subquery in conditional mutate

Tags: r, filter, subquery, dplyr

I want to compute a new row based on the result of a subquery in the same dataframe. Minimal (non) working example:

```
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(
  VAR1 = c("A", "A", "B", "C"),
  VAR2 = c("F", "G", "E", "D"),
  VAR3 = c("G", "F", "X", "D")
) %>% as_tibble

subquery <- function(v1, v2) {
  dplyr::filter(df, as.character(v1) == VAR1, as.character(v2) == VAR2)
}

TEST <-
  df %>%
  mutate(X = case_when(
    plyr::empty(subquery(VAR1, VAR3)) ~ "EMPTY",
    TRUE ~ "NON EMPTY"
  ))
```

The result dataframe TEST should be

```
VAR1   VAR2   VAR3   X        
<fctr> <fctr> <fctr> <chr>    
A      F      G      NON EMPTY
A      G      F      NON EMPTY
B      E      X      EMPTY
C      D      D      NON EMPTY
```

but is

```
VAR1   VAR2   VAR3   X        
<fctr> <fctr> <fctr> <chr>    
A      F      G      NON EMPTY
A      G      F      NON EMPTY
B      E      X      NON EMPTY
C      D      D      NON EMPTY
```

Many thanks in advance!

remark: If I don't coerce the `v1` and `v2` to `character` I get the following error:

```
Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: Evaluation error: level sets of factors are different..
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would put the `empty` function within the `subquery` function in order to return TRUE or FALSE values. Then it would be possible to vectorise it in order to apply it to every row of your dataframe:

```
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(
  VAR1 = c("A", "A", "B", "C"),
  VAR2 = c("F", "G", "E", "D"),
  VAR3 = c("G", "F", "X", "D")
) %>% as_tibble

subquery <- function(v1, v2) {
  empty(filter(df, as.character(v1) == VAR1, as.character(v2) == VAR2))
}

subquery = Vectorize(subquery)

  df %>%
  mutate(X = case_when(
    subquery(VAR1, VAR3) == FALSE ~ "NON EMPTY",
    TRUE ~ "EMPTY"
  ))

# # A tibble: 4 x 4
#   VAR1  VAR2  VAR3  X        
#   <fct> <fct> <fct> <chr>    
# 1 A     F     G     NON EMPTY
# 2 A     G     F     NON EMPTY
# 3 B     E     X     EMPTY    
# 4 C     D     D     NON EMPTY
```

Or you can put `empty` and `case_when` within the `subquery` function like this:

```
subquery <- function(v1, v2) {
  res = empty(filter(df, as.character(v1) == VAR1, as.character(v2) == VAR2))
  case_when(res == FALSE ~ "NON EMPTY",
            TRUE ~ "EMPTY")
}

subquery = Vectorize(subquery)

df %>% mutate(X = subquery(VAR1, VAR3))
```